# Pass array from crossplane claim to crossplane composition

Tags: kubernetes, crossplane

I am working on claim that will be used by about 8 services org wide, how do i pass the array of env variables to the composition. There seems to be no way of doing this

Here is an example of my claim

```
apiVersion: app.org.io/v1
kind: XClaim
metadata:
  name: test-app
spec:
  parameters:
    name: test-app
    envVariables:
    - variables:
        foo: bar
        name: precious
        age: 15
```

Here is an example of my CRD

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.crossplane.io/v1
kind: CompositeResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: applambdas.app.org.io
  namespace: crossplane-system
spec:
    group: app.org.io
    names:
        kind: AppLambda
        plural: applambdas
    versions:
        - name: v1
          served: true
          referenceable: true
          schema:
            openAPIV3Schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                spec:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    parameters:
                      type: object
                      properties:
                        env:
                          type: string
                        envVariables:
                          type: array
                        name:
                          type: string

    claimNames:
      kind: XClaim
      plural: xclaims
```

Here is an example of my composition

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.crossplane.io/v1
kind: Composition
metadata:
  name: lambda
spec:
  compositeTypeRef:
    apiVersion: app.org.io/v1
    kind: AppLambda
  resources:
    - name: lambda-function
      base:
        apiVersion: lambda.aws.upbound.io/v1beta1
        kind: Function
        metadata:
          annotations:
            uptest.upbound.io/timeout: "3600"
          name: lambda
        spec:
          providerConfigRef:
            name: aws-config
          forProvider:
            handler: index.lambda_handler
            packageType: Zip
            region: eu-west-1
            role: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/crossplane-lambda-test-role
            runtime: python3.9
            s3Bucket: testappbucket-upbound-provider-test-data
            s3Key: function.zip
            timeout: 60
            environment: []
      patches:
        - fromFieldPath: spec.parameters.envVariables[variables]
          toFieldPath: spec.forProvider.environment[variables]
```

The `spec.forProvider.environment` dosen't seem to get patched, I have been on this all week, please i need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the environment variables are not actually an array. You can see from the [crd](https://doc.crds.dev/github.com/upbound/provider-aws/lambda.aws.upbound.io/Function/v1beta1@v0.37.0#spec-forProvider-environment-variables) that `variables` should be the key to an object, stored underneath a single value `environment` array.

```yaml
spec:
  forProvider:
    environment:
    - variables:
        key: value
```

So with some small tweaks to your definition and composition, this should be possible:

```yaml
apiVersion: apiextensions.crossplane.io/v1
kind: CompositeResourceDefinition

...
    envVariables:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        type: string
...
```

```yaml
apiVersion: apiextensions.crossplane.io/v1
kind: Composition
...
    patches:
      - fromFieldPath: spec.parameters.envVariables
        toFieldPath: spec.forProvider.environment[0].variables
...
```

This will let you create a claim like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: app.org.io/v1
kind: XClaim
metadata:
  name: test-app
spec:
  parameters:
    name: test-app
    envVariables:
      foo: bar
      name: precious
      age: "15"
```

Resulting in a function with the appropriate environment variables set.
[AWS Console Showing Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gctlb.png)

Note: Environment Variable values must be strings, which is the reason for the validation in the schema and the quotes in the claim.